# Encrypt password (RSA) with public key

Tags: php, encryption, certificate, rsa, pem

I'm having serious problems with what I was hoping would be a simple call to  PHP's 
`openssl_public_encrypt();`

Sadly, I get an invalid public key warning.

My goal is to simply RSA encrypt a users password using public key provided by their API which currently looks like this:

> +Tir6+unMOaQ5tHqjjjwnlAMhccnCSMFEi3a0mhIxbW+O/GukjomGyzckQT2h0Ys70JezHbNq5YS3sYkNF29kCkz4HuNfy9eEjE/clA9/zyfT8ZcbnusLcLz2xNgbTp62fQdzBnReI5+dpj/N24krYvHaYIr8ACxDqBv2TR3E9M=AQAB

Apparently a working implementation using the same service I'm trying to use found a solution with these steps:

1. Extract the modulus and exponent from the public key
2. Re-constructs the key in the MS PUBLICKEYBLOB format
3. Call OpenSSL to convert the key to PEM format
4. Load the PEM public key from the converted file
5. Encrypts the password (after converting to UTF-16LE)

However not only that I dont know if its possible to do in PHP , I think there Must be an easier way!

One post I saw hinted that the exponent may come after the last = sign (so AQAB) but I don't know if this is reliable.

Comment: Why do you want to encrypt a password and not hash it?

Comment: I really don't understand why they don't just accept a hash or even use HTTPS for the SOAP service. It is ludicrous. Even if they insist on RSA encryption like this, surely it is unnecessary to have to create a certificate on the fly. Sadly, it is not my API to edit.

Comment: No, you cannot use that last = sign to split, just removing the AQAB may work though. If the key is a multiple of 3 bytes (e.g. 3072 bits) then there will be no = sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this do what you want?:

```
<?php
$key = '+Tir6+unMOaQ5tHqjjjwnlAMhccnCSMFEi3a0mhIxbW+O/GukjomGyzckQT2h0Ys70JezHbNq5YS3sYkNF29kCkz4HuNfy9eEjE/clA9/zyfT8ZcbnusLcLz2xNgbTp62fQdzBnReI5+dpj/N24krYvHaYIr8ACxDqBv2TR3E9M=AQAB';

include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey(array(
    'e' => new Math_BigInteger(65537),
    'n' => new Math_BigInteger(substr($key, 0, -4), -256)
));
$ciphertext = $rsa->encrypt('password');

echo bin2hex($ciphertext);
?>
```

This example uses [phpseclib, a pure PHP RSA implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/index.html). Although phpseclib does not support the format of the key you posted it does support raw public keys and as such converting to PKCS1 style keys is unnecessar. And the ciphertext's produced by phpseclib are perfectly [interoperable with OpenSSL](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/interop.html).

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing. THanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what you need to do:

1. remove the `AQAB` part and use the value 65537 for the public exponent
2. base 64 decode the modulus
3. create a DER encoding of the public key in PKCS#1 format (see below)
4. base64 encode the DER encoding using 64 character line length and DOS line endings
5. add PEM header & footer
6. use the PEM encoded string to create a public key and finally
7. encrypt the password

---

The following ASN.1 spec defines the public key in PKCS#1 format:

```
RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
      modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
      publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e
}
```

Now the identifier octet or tag of SEQUENCE is `30` in hex, INTEGER is `02` and the length should be specified [like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#The_definite_form). So you get something like:

```
30818902818100F938ABEBEBA730E690E6D1EA8E38F09E500C85C727092305122DDAD26848C5B5BE3BF1AE923A261B2CDC9104F687462CEF425ECC76CDAB9612DEC624345DBD902933E07B8D7F2F5E12313F72503DFF3C9F4FC65C6E7BAC2DC2F3DB13606D3A7AD9F41DCC19D1788E7E7698FF376E24AD8BC769822BF000B10EA06FD9347713D30203010001
```

in hexadecimals. So after base 64 encoding and adding the header and footer line you should get:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQH5OKvr66cw5pDm0eqOOPCeUAyFxycJIwUSLdrSaEjFtb478a6SOiYbLNyRBPaHRizvQl7Mds2rlhLexiQ0Xb2QKTPge41/L14SMT9yUD3/PJ9Pxlxue6wt
wvPbE2BtOnrZ9B3MGdF4jn52mP83biSti8dpgivwALEOoG/ZNHcT0wIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

---

Happy coding.

Comment: This was a helpful post but in the end it was simpler to use a Crypt_RSA from pspseclib ( as outlined in neubert's reply). Thanks very much

Comment: @TomBrown No problem, don't forget to accept neuberts answer! You cannot vote up yet (not enough rep) but once you can you may also vote up answers.